# Find Transition Probability Matrix of 7 Series of Game

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Two teams, A and B, are to play a best of seven series of games.
Suppose that the outcomes of successive games are independent, and each
is won by A with probability $p$ and won by B with probability $1 - p$. Let
the state of the system be represented by the pair $(a, b)$, where $a$ is the
number of games won by A, and $b$ is the number of games won by B.
Specify the transition probability matrix. Note that $a + b\leq7$ and that the
series ends whenever $a = 4$ or $b = 4$.

I've found the states
$(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(0,4)$
$(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4)$
$(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4)$
$(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4)$
$(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)$

Is that states correct? How to find the transition probability matrix?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this list is correct.

For a typical state $(a, b)$, there are only two possible transitions, namely to $(a + 1, b)$, with probability $p$, and to $(a, b + 1)$, with probability $1 - p$. So, the column of the transition probability matrix corresponding to state $(a, b)$ only has two nonzero entries, corresponding to these states. By contrast, the states $(a, 4)$ and $(4, b)$ are absorbing.

Comment: how to find the transition probability matrix? is the size of the matrix is $24\times24$?

Comment: I've edited my answer to make clear that "column" refers to a column of the transition probability matrix. And yes, since there are $24$ states, the transition matrix will be $24 \times 24$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you found it useful.